# How to allow user registration and allow them to upload videos?

Tags: files

I am creating a video sharing website like youtube, dailymotion etc. So I need to allow registered users to upload videos when they come to their profile on my website.

I have already setup a media content type with images and video options.

How can I allow users to create it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to upload a Youtube video in your website, there is the [Youtube field](https://drupal.org/project/youtube) module which enables you to upload videos from Youtube by putting the link in the field.

If you want to upload a video from any site use the [Media](https://drupal.org/project/media) module for this.

> The YouTube field module provides a simple field that allows you to add a youtube video to a content type, user, or any entity.
>
> Display types include:
>
> - YouTube videos of various sizes.
> - YouTube thumbnails with image styles.
>
> This module is a lightweight alternative to [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) or [Embedded Media Field](http://drupal.org/project/emfield), if you're looking for a way to add video fields from more than one provider, you may want to consider looking into either of those two modules.

> The Media module provides an extensible framework for managing files and multimedia assets, regardless of whether they are hosted on your own site or a 3rd party site - it is commonly referred to as a 'file browser to the internet'.
>
> Media is a drop-in replacement for the Drupal core upload field with a unified User Interface where editors and administrators can upload, manage, and reuse files and multimedia assets. Any files uploaded before Media was enabled will automatically take advantage of the many of the features it comes with.

Answer (score 0):

Simply allow users register on your site, give permissions to the authenticated users to allow them create contents of the content type you created on the permissions page **admin/people/permissions**. The permission should be under category Node and would look like this

> Your content type name: Create new content

And on your navigation block, if they have permission a link to create that content type would show up

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up permission to upload node of that content type and edit own content for authenticated user (admin/people/permissions)

Then create a user, login and try to upload a couple of videos.

Then use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) to create a list of content of that content type for that user.
[Views Documentantion](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views)